# Reading Japanese query parameters from the URL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, character-encoding, charset

I am getting query parameter as `"&atilde;\\u0083\\u008e&atilde;\\u0083&frac14;&atilde;\\u0083\\u0096&atilde;\\u0083&copy;&atilde;\\u0083&sup3;&atilde;\\u0083\\u0089&aring;\\u0093\\u0081"` in my controller for Japanese character "ノーブランド品".

Is there a way to translate all query parameters into UTF-8?
I have tried multiple solutions but it does not seem to be working
Solution I tried

```
URLDecoder.decode(string, "UTF-8");
```

Another solution I tried is

```
 ByteBuffer buffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(encodedName);
 decodedName = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(buffer).toString();
```

Is there a way to decode the string back to Japanese once it is translated? Reason am asking is because page that is calling us is not owned by us

Thanks

Comment: The query parameter in the question seems to be already garbled. How did you send the request to the server? When you send the string `ノーブランド品` as UTF-8 string, it should be encoded to `%E3%83%8E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E5%93%81`.